# How to unversion some files (or folders) from a svn working copy?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

At first I should say that I'm not looking for a solution about `svn:ignore` or `svn rm --keep-local`, and I don't want to unversion the whole working copy, now there is only 1 `.svn` folder for working copy, so `svn export` or deleting the `.svn` folder is not the answer I want too.

What I want is unversion (unlink, untrack... I'm not sure which word to use) some items under a working copy that are already checked out or updated.

I've also tried "Unversion and add to ignore list" in TortoiseSVN, but it looks like a combination command of `svn:ignore` and `svn rm --keep-lock`. Adding a file to `ignore-on-commit` changelist is much better, but I can't add a folder in this way.

Let me elaborate.

I have 2 files in a repository.

```
repo-url
  a.txt
  b.txt
```

Check out.

```
>svn co --depth empty repo-url wd
>cd wd
>svn up a.txt
```

Now only `a.txt` is checked out, if I add `b.txt` to `wd` folder, svn recoginzes it is unversioned.

```
>echo abc>b.txt
>svn st
?     b.txt
>del b.txt
>svn st
```

If I incautiously update `b.txt`, this file is versioned by svn. If I delete this file locally, svn will mark the working copy as modified.

```
>svn up b.txt
>del b.txt
>svn st
!     b.txt
```

I can't find a simple command to revert my working copy to the state before updating `b.txt`. Currently my solution is deleting the related rows in `.svn/wc.db/NODES`, but I'm afraid to collapse the working copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem to work.

```
svn up --set-depth=exclude b.txt
```